# Internal DNS points to internal server, yet site resolves to public site?

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2012-r2, internal-dns

We have a website `website.test.company.com` and in internal DNS (server 2012 r2) it has 10.0.0.21, which is our server address internally. However when we type in `www.website.test.company.com` it resolves to `website.com` and shows the live page instead of our test server? I cannot think of why this would be can anyone point me in a direction, in my mind the http path shouldnt even get outside of the gateway?

Comment: IS www.website.test.company.com configured as a CNAME RECORD to website.test.company.com in the internal DNS?

Comment: It is configured as an A name

Comment: `website.test.company.com`, `www.website.test.company.com` are two separate things. Add in `website.com` and you're talking about three. Some detail might help clarify.

Comment: oh, fair enough. I think that may be it.

Comment: I added `www.website.test` and it then resolved to the public site at `www.website.com`, there was no www in internal dns. Now there is and they both resolve to the public `www.website.com`

Comment: it resolves...or does it 301 redirect to the other url

Answer (score 10):

In the world of DNS `website.test.company.com` and `www.website.test.company.com` are two completely different URLs.

Whether you are running Windows or Linux and your webserver you need to make you sure have either an alias for `www.website.test.company.com` or a binding in IIS for `www.website.test.company.com`

You also want to make sure you have a CNAME record setup on your internal DNS for `www.website.test.company.com` or if you want create a new A record for `www.website.test.company.com`